# Flutter: await and then - baffling behavior

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

```
ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker(); // from image_picker.dart

try {
      XFile? pickedFile = await _picker.pickImage(source: source);
      do xyz;
}
catch (e){
      ...something
}
```

vs

```
try {
      _picker.pickImage(source: source).then((file) {do xyz;});
}
catch (e){
      ...something
}
```

The file select dialog opens. If I cancel without selecting a file, this is the behavior:

Case 1: await - neither 'do xyz' or the catch block is executed - the function just returns

case 2: then - the 'do xyz' block is executed

What is going on?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?  There should not be any different with respect to `do xyz`.  The `try`/`catch` blocks in the two examples are not equivalent, however.

Comment: To be clear: please provide [minimal reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that other people can run to observe the behavior you claim.  As your question currently stands, it seems very likely that you are *not* performing a proper apples-to-apples comparison and likely are misinterpreting your observations.

Answer (score 0):

What you claim is just not possible. The `do xyz` line in the first example will execute if it executes in the second example. It will just execute a bit later in time.

These two examples are quite similar but there is one difference: the second one's try/catch does not catch the async errors here. To fix that and to make the two examples exactly the same, you need to add an `await` to the second one. Now these two are exactly the same:

```
try {
      XFile? pickedFile = await _picker.pickImage(source: source);
      do xyz;
}
catch (e){
      ...something
}
```

```
try {
      await _picker.pickImage(source: source).then((file) {do xyz;});
}
catch (e){
      ...something
}
```

Because otherwise you initiate an async job but not await it, the execution gets out of the try/catch immediately and it cannot catch errors that will happen later.

Comment: var pickedFile = await _picker.pickImage(source: source);
var abc = 5;

the abc=5 line gets called only if I pick a file.

Comment: also now adding the await as in

await _picker.pickImage(source: source).then((pf) {
        pickedFile = pf;
      });
      var abc = 5;

again abc=5 is not called...

Comment: that's what's supposed to be. until you pick a file that future does not complete. in your second example the do xyz does not execute until you pick a file, either.

Comment: got that - but if I 'cancel' and do not pick a file I'm supposed to know that. The documentation says if a file is not picked it will return null....

Comment: The behavior is equivalent to the event not having been fired at all - as if that thread just dies

Comment: @SunilGupta Please provide real code that reproduces the behavior you're observing. `await` is syntactic sugar for registering a `Future.then` callback.  If no exception is thrown, there should not be any difference in behavior.

Comment: onDoubleTap: () async {
        if (!cameraLoading) {
          buttonPressed = true; << comes here
          var fd = await _onFileSelectPressed(ImageSource.gallery, context);
          setState(() {
            fileData = fd; << does not come here
          });
        }
      }, 

=============

Future<FileData?> _onFileSelectPressed(ImageSource source) async {
    XFile? pickedFile;

    try {
      await _picker.pickImage(source: source).then((pf) {
        pickedFile = pf; << does not execute
      });
      if (pickedFile != null) { << does not execute

Comment: When you cancel you get null. So it won't go into if (pickedFile != null) when you cancel. You are confused there. Put more ifs and breakpoints, you'll realize that when you cancel those lines actually execute and give you null.

Comment: @GazihanAlankus - I do know that (pickedFile != null) will not execute - but you will agree that the expression has to be evaluated, right? So, the debugger "next" must go to that line and THEN skip the if block. The debugger does not go anywhere, not even the pickedFile = pf portion that is after the .then

Comment: You should add print lines there and not expect debugger next to show you each line. Sometimes things may be optimized away.